# Are there any canon discrepancies preventing the Warhammer universe from being the future of the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, warhammer-40k

Talk about clash of the worlds!

The Star Trek universe to my knowledge only extends up to the 29th centuary (or the 2.9th millenia), has had something similar to the [STC disaster](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Computer_%28episode%29) and features a 'golden age' of exploration and colonization.

The Warhammer 40k universe is some 37 thousand years into the future, compared to ST, and most of their history is wiped out.

Is there anything (besides decency, and respect for canon) stopping one becoming the other? I'm looking for a specific example that precludes this possibility, such as "The years covering Star Trek are covered in resources X and nothing matching that tech fits from the Warhammer universe" or "The Star Trek universe in the year 40K is know to be Y".

Comment: WH40k doesn't have time travel police, or time travel at all. I suppose they  could all get lost in a fixed-point-in-time-war? ;)

Comment: @Nick, Actually, there are at least two 40k novels and a short story that involve time travel in two different ways, but I'll give you that none of them were policed in any way :)

Comment: The distinct absence of technobabble pretty much clinches it. Unless WH40K talks about the isolinear pulse modulation reversing the polarity of the tachyonic burst apparatus in the deflector shields...

Comment: Yes they do, but they've ben transformed into prayers and rituals tot he Machine Spirit (hitherto known as 'Computer'?)

Comment: @JohnO: That's totally nonsense! We all know that there is no such thing as a "tachyonic burst apparatus" in the deflector *dish*...but it can be reconfigured to omit one. \*ducks\*

Comment: With a time lapse of some 35,000 years just about anything is possible. Earth could have had 3 complete regressions into the stone-age and back in that amount of time. But if ST did lead into WH40K one would have to wonder what happened to all the Trek races (Vulcans, Klingons, Romulans, Borg etc)?

Comment: @DVK I think your title edit made the question harder to read

Comment: @Izkata - better?

Comment: @DVK I think so  =P

Comment: The issue with this question has little to do with the title.  It's just a twist on Shark vs. Gorilla, where instead of pitting two disparate creatures against each other, two disparate franchises are pitted against each other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two universes are not compatible. Humanity's technological advancement in the Warhammer 40k universe was thousands of years slower than it was in the Star Trek universe.

In the Warhammer universe, humanity didn't leave the Solar system until after the fifteenth millennium and didn't invent faster than light travel or encounter aliens until after the eighteenth millennium.

At the back of the Horus Heresy novel Galaxy in Flames, by Ben Counter, is a time line of Humanity:

> Millenium 1-15 Age of Terra Humanity dominates Earth. Civilisations
>   come and go. The Solar system is colonised. Mankind lives on Mars and
>   the moons of Jupiter, Saturn and Neptune.
>
> Millenium 15-18 Age of Technology Mankind begins to colonise the stars
>   using sub-light spacecraft. At first, only nearby systems can be
>   reached and the colonies established on them must survive  as
>   independent states since they are separated from Earth by up to ten
>   generations of travel
>
> Millenium 18-22 Age of Technology Invention of the warp-drive
>   accelerates the colonising of the galaxy. [...]. First aliens are
>   encountered and first Alien Wars are fought.